# How to get Visual C++ to warn about silent conversion of int to string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How do I get the compiler (vc14) to warn about this? I understand why it happens (int silently converts to char, and then to string as it has a char constructor). But its a source of bugs, and its bitten me more than once. Is there anything that can be done?

```
    int i = 1;
    std::string s;
    s = i; //"\x1"
```

Comment: I think you should enable the following warning: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th7a07tz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I ended up turning on /Wall (manually setting a couple of warnings off) and "Treat Warnings as errors". I should have done so a long time ago. It would have saved me some headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a comment but I think it should be extended to a proper answer:

`std::string` can be assigned to `char`, so there is no way to get around that.

What you can do is to make the compiler warn you when an `int` is downcasted to `char`, which might cause loss of data.

The warning you have to define is `C4244` (see level 3 and 4 in project properties)

More info on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th7a07tz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use Warning Level 4 (`/W4`), which you should really use for all code if possible.

> warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data

For various reasons, Visual C++ still defaults to Warning Level 3.

In fact, for code that you want to hold to a very high quality bar (like libraries used by a lot of people), you should enable all warnings (`/Wall`) and then disable just those warnings that are informational rather than actionable (or you truly consider noise). See ["Off By Default" Compiler Warnings in Visual C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c.aspx) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx)

In the case of heavily used shared libraries, you should SAL annotate the code and use `/analyze` as well. See [Analyzing C/C++ Code Quality by Using Code Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182025.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-Wconversion`

**Given this example**:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
        int i = 1;
        ::std::string s;
        s = i;
        return 0;
}
```

**Compilation results**:

```
g++ -Wconversion foo.cpp 
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:6:4: warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
  s = i;
    ^
```

Comment: Compiler-specific answer. What if the OP is not using gcc ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Good point, I missed the vc14 part. I don't use that compiler but I will leave this anyway

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you should enable all warnings by adding `-Wall -Wextra` flags while compiling.

You could also try `-Wconstant-conversion` flag.